# OnCompleteListener is not called for .setValue in RealtimeDatabase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to save data to a Firebase Realtime-Database. I just simply want to save data with

```
databaseReference.child("someChild").setValue(someObject);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

and this just works fine. The Object appears in the console, and everything works. But I wondered if there was a smoother implementation, so I tried to use `OnCompleteListener`
and worked out the following code:

```
final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

databaseReference.child("someChild")
    .setValue(someObject)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                System.out.println("completed");
                done.set(true);
            }
        });

    while (!done.get());
```

Again, the data is written successfully to the database, but the `onCompleteListener` is not called at all and therefore the `while`-loop isn't interrupted.

Why isn't the Listener called? I did other setups as well (without the `while`-loop), but those didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the tight loop (the `while` loop you have) will block the main thread and keep Firebase from calling `onComplete` (which also happens on the main thread.

To prevent the blocking, use something like `postDelayed`:

```
final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

databaseReference.child("someChild")
    .setValue(someObject)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            System.out.println("completed");
            done.set(true);
        }
    });

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (done.get()) {
       ... Do the thing that requires the data
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Also see my answer here [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. The `OnComplete`-Listener still isn't called (if it was, I would have seen it in the SystemOutput)

Comment: If you remove the `AtomicBoolean` and the effort to wait, does it call `onComplete()`? If so, it is clear that the code you removed is blocking the call to `onComplete()`.

Comment: Turned out, that the `AtomicBoolean` was indeed the problem. Thanks for your help!